# MassTransit - Where to store state between retries

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using MassTransit (and RabbitMq for the queues) to do some sequential processing of each message that involves a number of steps.

I want to be able to store a "processing-state" info somewhere in `IConsumeContext<MyMessage>` that will be related to each particular message, so that e.g., if a message processing fails at step 2, on  the next retry I would continue from step 2 and not repeat step 1 again.

Is that possible?

Some possible ways I see is to change the message itself, but I don't know if this is standard way of doing things.

Also, there is a `Headers` property on the message, but I am not sure what's this for.

Has anyone done this before?

**UPDATE:**

I might just use `try/catch` blocks with loops and delay inside there too, but I don't know if it would be better to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle something like this is a Saga via [Automatonymous](https://github.com/MassTransit/Automatonymous). Make retries explicit and part of your domain.

We already do retries at the lower level, if an exception is thrown it's tossed back on the queue and retried until max retries are hit. Then the message is tossed in the error queue. You can also call `RetryLater()` on the context. There's a retry count in the header for things like counting retries already.